# Hide/Remove Text in the Column in CRM View "Items Available To Work on" for Queue Item entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

When a user opens the view "Items Available To Work on" for QueueItem entity, a related entity's column is showing some data in the view. I want to remove or hide that data when another column in the view has some specific data in it.

Here is the actual example which I need to achieve.

When the field "Case Type" has text "Revenue Collection" then hide text "Dummy Taxpayer" from the field "Taxpayer". Both fields are showing from related entity Case in this QueueItem view.

> [image: Queue Item]

I have checked the following possibilities but these are not working.

1- RetrieveMultiple message cannot be used with the QueueItem entity.

2- Tried with entity "SavedQuery" on RetrieveMultiple, but that is giving FetchXML of the view. We cannot change the result of the FetchXML dynamically here also.

3- In the properties of the column "Taxpayer" in the view, we do not have the option to run a JavaScript as my CRM version is 2016. This feature is available in Dynamics 365.

So, there is no supported way to achieve this as per my understanding. Any help/suggestion is appreciated on this issue

Comment: The link in the question named "Queue Item" is the screenshot of the issue which needs to be resolved.

Comment: Is your View Editable?
Also is it ok for you iff your view is Editable, depending on condition your field is Disabled (not hidden)
As far as I know you cannot hide/show column in view based on some condition

Comment: Yes, the view is Editable in the sense that we can add/remove columns in the view. The view "Items available to work on" in the default view in which I have added fields from related case entity. I do not need to hide/show columns but I just want to hide text/data showing in that specific column if the column "Case Type" has specific text

Comment: no you cannot do that, Either you can disable/enable it or you can use field security profile so that this field will be shown only to specific users who have Field security role.

Comment: Ok, if we need to enable disable a column in the view based on condition in CRM 2016, how it can be done?

Comment: Added an aswer.

Answer (score 0):

In Grid,

You cannot Hide/show column dynamically depending on your condition. Rather you can enable/disable field so that users cannot edit field based on Condition.

Please find [Link Article](https://bettercrm.blog/2017/04/18/disable-columns-in-editable-grid/) as Example.

Comment: This is related to the Editable grid. We are in CRM 2016 and the listing is default list of entity QueueItem. This is not an editable grid.

Comment: I think I asked as very first comment View Editable?
Anyhow when your view/grid is not editable then user cannot directly change it on grid?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I didn't say I am using the editable grid. As detailed earlier the view is OOB view which is "Items Available to work on" and the grid/listing which loads this is also OOB main grid which we can see for every entity when we want to seee records of that entity.

Comment: As mentioed, your grid is not editable therefore there is no question of enable/disable field. W.r.t hiding column vlaue in Grid, this is not possible in CRM

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a data captured problem rather than data hide/show problem.

When the case type is "Revenue Collection", the value of the "Tax payer" should be null. Then this problem is solved in grid/view or form and everywhere.

Comment: Anywhere in the system, case type is "Revenue Collection" we have set lookup of TaxPayer field with value "Dummy Taxpayer" by some process. We need to show the field TaxPayer with null/empty data in the views when the related  case type is "Revenue Collection". In simple words we cannot remove "Dummy Taxpayer" from DB but want to remove it on load of data in the views to pretend as this field has no data.

Comment: @user2050288 this is very rare requirement, probably you have to build your own Grid control using HTML webresource